# Is it possible to tell spring cloud sleuth to not log values like passwords?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-sleuth

So I enabled Spring Cloud Sleuth in my spring boot app and this happened:

```
2021-03-03 19:11:11.164 DEBUG [OAuth2 service,b1e3783b06d8cc61,b1e3783b06d8cc61] 5056 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{grant_type=[password], client_id=[myclientid], client_secret=[b0ea9376...], username=[rose], password=[mypassword]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

As you can see at the end, the Sleuth logged the `password=[mypassword]` what is not good... Not good at all.

Is it possible to configure Sleuth to not log sensitive data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see towards the beginning, this was not logged by Sleuth but by `RestTemplate`, the logger is `o.s.web.client.RestTemplate`, it has nothing to do with Sleuth.
([Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b9a612b6374163a1cc891f4f16e61937c3fef0bc/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.java#L1007) is the line that does this).

What Sleuth has to do with this log event is this part: `[OAuth2 service,b1e3783b06d8cc61,b1e3783b06d8cc61]`; the name of your service, the traceID and the spanID, none of them should be considered as secrets.

If you don't want `RestTemplate` to log out these details, you can set it's log level to `INFO`, `WARN` or higher.